# Linq query to compare 2 List<string> for distinct matches

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm new to Linq and have searched for this everywhere but could not find answer so excuse if already asked. I looking for a Linq query (ideally using the lambda/ method syntax) to compare 2 Lists:

```
IList<string> List1 = new List<string> { usr.User1, usr.User2, usr.User3, usr.User4 };

IList<string> List2 = new List<string>{ "Tim", "Bob", "Brian", "Paul" };
```

Basically I would like there to only be 4 possible matches, so if:

```
usr.User1 == "Tim", 
usr.User2 == "Bob", 
usr.User3 == "Brian", 
usr.User4 == "Paul"
```

I would ideally like it to return an int with a value from 0-4, so if all of the matches above were successful then it would return 4, if no matches successful then returns 0 etc. Many thanks.

Comment: Don't think you need to overcomplicate things unless you're trying to learn linq. A `for` statement would do the trick with 2 lines and would be more readable and debugeable.

Comment: Does position matter for you? e.g. If `User1` was Bob and `User2` was Tim, is the expected result 4 or 2?

Comment: Hi, only user1 can be Tim, user2 Bob etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List1.Zip(List2, (item1, item2) => item1 == item2 ? 1 : 0).Sum();
```

The function defined in Zip() will return 1 or 0, depending on whether or not the strings match, then you simply Sum() the results.

Comment: @kanchirk It only checks that the name exists in the list. The Zip() method will check if the first item in List1 is "Tim", the second item in List2 is "Bob", etc. Your solution would return 4 even if every name in List1 was "Brian".

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use an intersect. Like this:

```
    private class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TwoListsWithSameUsersReturnCorrectCountOfEquality()
    {
        var user1 = new User { UserName = "Tim" };
        var user2 = new User { UserName = "Bob" };
        var user3 = new User { UserName = "Brian" };
        var user4 = new User { UserName = "Paul" };

        IList<string> List1 = new List<string> 
                { user1.UserName, user2.UserName, user3.UserName, user4.UserName };

        IList<string> List2 = new List<string> { "Tim", "Bob", "Brian", "Paul" };

        var sameUser = List1.Distinct().Intersect(List2.Distinct());

        Assert.AreEqual(4, sameUser.Count());
    }
```

Note that the comparison is case sensitive. So tim will result in a count of 4 equal named users.

**Update**
This will indeed not take the order of the lists into account. This was not in the original question and I missed the comments before posting this. Without the order requirement this answer is still suitable.

Comment: this will ignore the order of elements

Comment: Where in the question is that a requirement??

Comment: I asked for clarification in the comments.