# find distinct matches in two List<string>

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and have searched for this everywhere but could not find answer so excuse if already asked. I am trying to use a for loop to compare 2 Lists:

```
IList<string> List1 = new List<string> { usr.User1, usr.User2, usr.User3, usr.User4 };

IList<string> List2 = new List<string>{ "Tim", "Bob", "Brian", "Paul" };
```

Basically I would like there to only be 4 possible matches, so only these possible matches should count:

```
usr.User1 == "Tim", // e.g. User1 has to be Tim etc.
usr.User2 == "Bob", 
usr.User3 == "Brian", 
usr.User4 == "Paul"
```

I would ideally like it to return an int with a value from 0-4, so if all of the matches above were successful then it would return 4, if no matches successful then returns 0 etc.

I have tried:

```
 int score = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i <= List2.Count; i++)
 {
    if (List1[i] == List2[i]) 
    {
        score++;
    }
 }
```

But currently getting IndexOutOfRangeException. Many thanks.

Comment: The reason for the exception is `<= List2.Count`. If count is 4 then the valid index values are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @User9876867 Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is very close to an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  In your example you are asking how to complish it using a [tag:for-loop] which is not only not required, but there are better ways to solve the actual problem which is simply *how do I match values in a list by index*.

Comment: Hi I was told to use for loop as it is more human readable and debuggable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `=`, you want to stop short of the upper bound.

```
for (int i = 0; i < List2.Count; i++)
```

The other option is to use [zip linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
int score = List1.Zip(List2, (a,b) => a == b ? 1 : 0).Sum();
```

Comment: This looks familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355314/linq-query-to-compare-2-liststring-for-distinct-matches/28355379#28355379

Comment: It's worth notating (seems as if the poster is new to C#) that collections are `0`-based. And `Count` properties are `1`-based.

Comment: @itsme86 pure coincidence. Great minds and all that!

Answer (score 2):

Lose the `=` it should be `for (int i = 0; i < List2.Count; i++)`.

There are probably better ways of doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

Since `List2` has 4 elements, `List2.Count` would be eqal to 4.

When you make the `i <= List2.Count` statement in the for loop, your are allowing the loop to indexes 0-4 because Lists are 0 index base and when the loop gets to index 4, an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception would be thrown.

The solution would be to change the `<=` statement in the for loop to `<`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to review the [Formatting Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). It will help your questions and answers look better and ultimately become more helpful. Also, we strongly encourage using "full" answers such as the ones other people have posted. :)

Comment: Thanks @Cameron, I will take your advise.